# How can I pass a list of arguments to another function in c++?

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I have a problem with function arguments. I have a function A which calls a function B. What do I have to write instead of ??? to archive that functionA passes all arguments to function B?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

void functionA(int a, ...);
void functionB(int a, ...);

int main()
{
    functionA(2, 5, 13);

    return 0;
}

void functionA(int a, ...)
{
    functionB(a, ??? );
}

void functionB(int a, ...)
{   
    va_list params;
    va_start(params, a);
    for(int i = 0; i<a; i++)
    {
        std::cout << va_arg(params, int) << std::endl;
    }
    va_end(params);
}
```

Comment: Do not use variable number of arguments. It is a silly idea and not type safe

Comment: Why do you want to make spaghetti?

Comment: You might want to look up variadic templates. They'll at least let you do this a little more cleanly (e.g., without destroying type-safety).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with `...`. If you rewrite `functionB` to take a `va_list` like `vprintf` does, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make *two* functions, one taking a variable number of arguments, and one taking a `va_list`.

```
void vunctionB(int a, va_list va)
{
    ...
}

void functionB(int a, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, a);
    functionB(a, va);
    va_end(va);
}
```

---

There might be other possible solutions as well, like using [variadic templates in C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).

Answer (score 0):

You need to design **two** versions of your function, one with valists, and one with variable arguments:

```
void vfunctionA(int a, va_list ap)
{
    // real logic
}

void functionA(int a, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, a);
    vfunctionA(a, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

// same for functionB
```

Now you can easily implement one function in terms of another:

```
double vrandom(int x, va_list ap)
{
    return vfunctionX(x, ap);
}
```

If you check the standard library or the Posix library, you'll find tons of examples for this, e.g. `printf`/`vprintf`, `execl`/`execv` (but not `fork`/`vfork`!).